# How do you allow Neovim CoC to see include directories

Tags: clang, neovim

Coc in Neovim seems to be unable to see `#include <avr/io.h>` since I'm guessing that it's include path isn't known by coc. How can I allow coc to see this include path?

Comment: This has nothing to do with coc. Which language server are you using? Check the language server documentation.

Comment: @jdhao I'm using clangd

Comment: This might be of some help: https://jdhao.github.io/2021/07/03/install_clangd_on_linux/#how-to-use-clangd. You need to set up the correct compilation flags, include paths etc.

Comment: @jdhao what I cant figure out is how to get clangd to use `compilation_flags.txt` or `compile_commands.json`. I think it has to do with configureing `coc-settings.json` but I'm not sure at all where to start with that. I though that [this](https://github.com/neoclide/coc.nvim/wiki/Using-the-configuration-file) page would have some information, but it wasn't much help.

Comment: For me, I just put `compile_flags.txt` in project (note it is **not** `compilation_flags.txt`) root and autocompletion starts to work. I am using the builtin nvim lsp client though. I have no knowledge about coc.nvim. My config is [here](https://github.com/jdhao/nvim-config), if you are interested.

Comment: @jdhao Ok, so I tried putting the `compile_flags.txt` in the root of the folder, and added `-I /usr/avr/include` to it, but it still didn't add the autocompletion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution was found to be the following:

1. In the root of your project directory (the base of compilation) add a file called `compile_flags.txt`.
2. To the `compile_flags.txt` file, for the AVR includes, add `-I/usr/avr/include`.

**NOTE:** The `compile_flags.txt` file only accepts a single argument per line, so the actual contents of this file should be

```
-I
/usr/avr/include
```

References:
[JSON Compilation Database Format Specification](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/JSONCompilationDatabase.html)

Comment: See also `https://clangd.llvm.org/installation.html#project-setup`.